# Non-number-theoretic class field theory?

Tags: reference-request, class-field-theory

This is a curiosity-oriented question, so references or indications are very welcomed.
[In the book on class field theory by Neukirch](http://books.google.com.tw/books/about/Class_field_theory.html?id=5_vuAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), one finds an abstract version of class-field theory: for a profinite group $G$, a $G$-module $A$, and two maps $\deg$: $G\to \hat Z$, $v: A_k\to \hat Z$ satisfying certain conditions($v$ is a henselian valuation with respect to $\deg$), one calls the pair $(\deg,v)$ a *class-field theory*.
In view of the above generality in stating the conditions, one is thus led to ask:

> Are there nay applications of class-field theory outside the realm of number-theory? For example, is there some kind of *statistic class-field theory*? Or is this thought too imaginative after all?

Any responses are the most appreciated in advance.

Comment: I haven't heard of *statistic class field theory* yet, but fall over a paper using class field theory in a totally different environment than number theory, see [this link](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702379).

Comment: It looks like an interesting article; thanks for sharing. :)